# Please check my calculations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, collision, protons

Let us consider the equation:
$p+p\to p+p+\pi^o$
In the Center Of Mass reference Frame,
The total momentum of the system is zero.Both before and after the collision.In the lab frame one of the proton is at rest and the other one is moving with velocity $v_{lab}$ .So,in the CM reference frame both of them moves with velocity $v_{cm}$.Using conservation of relativistic energy:

\begin{align} 
    &2m_{p}c^2\gamma=2m_{p}c^2+m_{\pi}c^2\\
    &\implies \gamma=\frac{2m_{p}+m_{\pi}}{2m_{p}}\\
    &\implies \gamma \approx 1.07\\
    &\implies \beta \approx 0.366\\
    &\implies V_{cm}=0.366c \\
    &\implies v_{\pi ,lab}=\frac{U_{cm}+V_{cm}}  {1+\frac{U_{cm}V_{cm}}{c^2}} \\
    &\implies v_{\pi,lab}=0.366c
\end{align}
and
$$
v_{p},lab=\frac{2V_{cm}}{1+\frac{V_{cm}^2}{c^2}}
$$
\begin{align}
    v_{p,lab}=0.64c\implies \gamma=1.3
\end{align}
so,
$$
E_{p,lab}=m_{p}c^2\gamma=1.23 GeV
$$

Now let us consider the equation for production for $K^+$ in a p-p inelastic collision:

$$
p+p\to p+\Lambda^0+K^+
$$

Using similar calculations we get:
\begin{align}
    &\gamma_{cm} \approx 1.36\\
    &\implies v_{p,lab}=0.92c\\
    &\implies\gamma_{lab}=2.55
\end{align}
so,
\begin{align}
    E_{p,lab}\approx2.4GeV
\end{align}

\begin{align}
     \gamma_{cm} \approx 1.36 \implies v_{K^+,lab}=0.67c
\end{align}
Considering mean lifetime of $K^+$ to be about $1.23*10^-8s$. The $K^+$ can travel about:
$$
1.26*1.23*10^-8*0.61*3*10^8m=3.4m
$$
Therefore the relativistic total energy of the $K^+$
$$
E_{K^+,lab}=m_{K^+,lab}c^2\gamma=0.67 GeV
$$

Comment: *Please check my calculations* Checking calculations is not the purpose of this site.